# How to correctly setup Oauth 2 Authentication in YouTube V3 API

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, oauth-2.0, google-api-client

I have a console app that pulls video view counts data using the YouTube V3 API. I am using Oauth 2 for authentication and having issues.

I executed my application on 2 different servers at different times.

One machines authenticates successfully and returns the following message from the logs:

```
2013-05-08 09:51:45,691 [8] INFO  DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Prepared outgoing AccessTokenRefreshRequest (2.0) message for https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token: 
refresh_token: 1/m4PJx978kbEGkQTf6tvSJdFCzej1Na6NBTakhhHQKjs
grant_type: refresh_token
client_id: 1085346326111.apps.googleusercontent.com
client_secret: HHH5WFqTRdXMl54rNZaUghNa
```

The other doesn’t authenticate successfully and I am assuming its waiting for permission to submit YouTube Data API requests on the user's behalf:

2013-05-08 09:44:59,442 [31] INFO  DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Prepared outgoing EndUserAuthorizationRequest (2.0) message for https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth: 
    response_type: code
    client_id: 1085346326111.apps.googleusercontent.com
    redirect_uri:server local host path
    scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly

Can anyone give me an explanation why the App may not be able to authenticate on one server  based on the fact that both servers are using the same code, same clientID and same Secret Key?

Here is a snippet of my code:

private void Oauth2Authenticate()
        {

```
        try
        {

            var provider = new NativeApplicationClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description)
                {
                    ClientIdentifier = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Client.Id"],
                    ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Client.Secret"]


                };

            var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator<NativeApplicationClient>(provider, GetAuthorization);

            youtube = new YoutubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    Authenticator = auth
                });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (logger != null)
            logger.Error(string.Format("Error authenticating Aplication on YouTube authentiction server", e.Message), e);
        }

    }



    private static IAuthorizationState GetAuthorization(NativeApplicationClient client)
    {
        var storage = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.ToString();

        var key = "storage_key";

        IAuthorizationState state = AuthorizationMgr.GetCachedRefreshToken(storage, key);
        if (state != null)
        {
            client.RefreshToken(state);
        }
        else
        {
            state = AuthorizationMgr.RequestNativeAuthorization(client, YoutubeService.Scopes.YoutubeReadonly.GetStringValue());
            AuthorizationMgr.SetCachedRefreshToken(storage, key, state);
        }

        return state;
    }
```